# how to dulipcate text fields in form using jquerys

Tags: jquery, html

i

```html
<form action="TrailUi" method="post" class="styled_form"
  onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="myForm">
  <div id="smallBox">
   Step <select name="option">
    <option value="">Select your Option</option>
    <option value="Click">Click</option>
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
   </select> <br>
   <input type="text" name="area1" value="" placeholder="object1" /> 
   <br><input type="text" name="area2" value="" placeholder="object2" />
   </div><br> 
   <input type="button" id="cloneButton1" class="styled-button-5" value="+" />
   <br><br><input type="submit" class="styled-button-5" value="Generate" />
 </form>
```

pls help me. in above code once press the + button .the text fields must be dulicated.

Comment: can you explain little more ? you mean add new text field with the plus button

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: no actually i want all three fields to added once i press the + button. also help in adding it to the database through servlet and jdbc

Comment: consider the three fields as batch which form a row in the table in database. now when press add button den the three field should be added and also when click on generate den two different row should be added to the database.how can i achieve dis

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
index = 1;
        $('#cloneButton1').click(function(){
            index++;
            $('#input-holder').append('<input type="text" name="area'+ index +'" value="" placeholder="object'+ index +'" /><br>');
        });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form action="TrailUi" method="post" class="styled_form"
  onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="myForm">
  <div id="smallBox">
   Step <select name="option">
    <option value="">Select your Option</option>
    <option value="Click">Click</option>
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
   </select> 
            <br>
            <div id="input-holder">
   <input type="text" name="area1" value="" placeholder="object1" /> <br>
   </div>
   </div>
            <br> 
   <input type="button" id="cloneButton1" class="styled-button-5" value="+" />
   <br><br><input type="submit" class="styled-button-5" value="Generate" />
 </form>
```

I hope this helps